# Looping through CoreData ManagedObject's Relationship

Tags: objective-c, optimization, core-data, foreach, entity-relationship

I have a situation where I have a list of `ObjectA`. `ObjectA` has a many-to-many relationship with `ObjectB`. I need to iterate through the list of `ObjectA` and store all the names of the `ObjectB` references.

The way I am currently doing this points to the actual for-loop as being 89.5% of execution time using Instruments:

```
for (ObjectA *a in listA) {
        [names removeAllObjects];
        for (ObjectB *b in a.objectBs) { //This is 89.5% of the execution time
            [names addObject:b.name];
        }
}
```

What are some ways to handle this better?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer you are asking for but maybe it solves your problem. Why do you need those names?

Couldn't you use a predicate for looping through nested lists? I don't know if the performance is better but as you are using CoreData I would try.

I used a predicate that loops through nested lists like this. I made it with the predicate editor of Xcode3. But Xcode4 has also a editor.

```
    NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY keywords.word contains[cd] %@",  self.searchBar.text];

    [fetchedResultsControllerSearch.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];



NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self fetchedResultsControllerSearch] performFetch:&error]) {
    // Handle error
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(-1);  // Fail
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your loop. The only results that would end up in `names` would be the the `b.name`'s from the very last `a.objectBs` in `listA`.

How about trying something like:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"objectB"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.objectAs contains %@", listA); 
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

// execute
```

This would return all of the `objectBs` that have an `objectA` in their `objectA` relation. You could then call `objectB.name` at the point you require the name.

PS the naming of your example makes this 50 million times harder to follow.